# Error in updating lookup (to user) with queue id...urgent help needed

Tags: apex, trigger

I am writing a simple before trigger to update a lookup field on lead to user object with the id of owner of record (owner could be a user or a queue). But on update of record i am getting an error.

My code:

```
trigger FetchTccValues on Lead (before insert, before update) {

 Group queue = [Select Id, name from Group where type='Queue' and Name='TCC Counsellors'];
 List<GroupMember> queueMembers = [Select Group.Name, UserOrGroupId From GroupMember where GroupId =: queue.Id ]; 

 for( Lead le : Trigger.new ) {

      for (GroupMember qm :queueMembers  ) {

         if( le.ownerid == queue.Id || le.ownerid == qm.UserOrGroupId ) {

             le.TCC_Lead_Status__c = le.Status;
             le.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = le.ownerid;

         }



     }
 }
}
```

On updating a record I am getting error:

> Apex trigger FetchTccValues caused an unexpected exception, contact
>   your administrator: FetchTccValues: data changed by trigger for field
>   TCC Lead Owner: id value of incorrect type: 00Gp0000000kCaCEAU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the owner is user because you can't link a queue in a user's lookup.

There are many ways you can do this.

- You can do something like

---

```
if(String.ValueOf(le.ownerid.getSObjectType()) == 'User'){
        le.TCC_Lead_Status__c = le.Status;
        le.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = le.ownerid;
    }
```

- As user Record ID Prefix does not change so you can also hard code them.

---

```
if(le.ownerid.substring(0,3) == '005'){
    le.TCC_Lead_Status__c = le.Status;
    le.TCC_Lead_Owner__c  = le.ownerid;
}
```

Comment: But record owner could be a queue sometimes..... In that case there is no solution or workaround ?

Comment: @user3486888 nope because Salesforce don't allow us to link with a queue. Although you can create a text field and if this queue you can store ID in that field.

Comment: That's bad news for me :( ..Any way i also adopted the text field option......Thanks for the quick reply !